# merge K sorted lists, not working for edge cases, like null, and only 2 lists C++

Tags: c++

so the code works for when number of lists is greater than 3, and there are no null lists, but shows error when there are two or less lists or empty lists
i'm comparing first element of every list and pointing the S to the one with the minimum value, then I point the node with the minimum value to its next one until it's null, when all lists reach/become null, i break the loop and return head->next

```
for example
input = [[1,4,5],[1,3,4],[2,6]]
my output = [1,1,2,3,4,4,5,6]
expected = [1,1,2,3,4,4,5,6] this one is correct
but when a null list is there
example: input = [[1,4,5],[],[1,3,4],[2,6]]
it returns an error something like: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow on address 0x...... error continues

=================================================================
==32==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow on address 0x603000000060 at pc 0x000000381d29 bp 0x7ffd73c87f70 sp 0x7ffd73c87f68
READ of size 8 at 0x603000000060 thread T0
    #3 0x7f28a234a82f  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x2082f)
0x603000000060 is located 0 bytes to the right of 32-byte region [0x603000000040,0x603000000060)
allocated by thread T0 here:
    #6 0x7f28a234a82f  (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x2082f)
Shadow bytes around the buggy address:
  0x0c067fff7fb0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0c067fff7fc0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0c067fff7fd0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0c067fff7fe0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
  0x0c067fff7ff0: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
=>0x0c067fff8000: fa fa 00 00 00 07 fa fa 00 00 00 00[fa]fa fa fa
  0x0c067fff8010: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c067fff8020: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c067fff8030: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c067fff8040: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
  0x0c067fff8050: fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa fa
Shadow byte legend (one shadow byte represents 8 application bytes):
  Addressable:           00
  Partially addressable: 01 02 03 04 05 06 07 
  Heap left redzone:       fa
  Freed heap region:       fd
  Stack left redzone:      f1
  Stack mid redzone:       f2
  Stack right redzone:     f3
  Stack after return:      f5
  Stack use after scope:   f8
  Global redzone:          f9
  Global init order:       f6
  Poisoned by user:        f7
  Container overflow:      fc
  Array cookie:            ac
  Intra object redzone:    bb
  ASan internal:           fe
  Left alloca redzone:     ca
  Right alloca redzone:    cb
  Shadow gap:              cc
==32==ABORTING
```

code:

```
    /**
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * struct ListNode {
 *     int val;
 *     ListNode *next;
 *     ListNode() : val(0), next(nullptr) {}
 *     ListNode(int x) : val(x), next(nullptr) {}
 *     ListNode(int x, ListNode *next) : val(x), next(next) {}
 * };
 */
class Solution {
public:
    ListNode* mergeKLists(vector<ListNode*>& lists) {
        ListNode* S = new ListNode();
        ListNode* head = S;
        int N = lists.size();
        int min = 0, count = 1;
        
        while ( count )
        {
            int k = 0;
            while( lists[k] == NULL && k < N )
                ++k;
            if( k == N  )
                break;
            min = k;
            count = 0;
            for(int j = 0; j < N; j++ )
            {
                if (lists[j] != NULL )
                {
                    if( lists[j]->val < lists[min]->val)
                        min = j;
                    
                    ++count;
                }
            }
            if( count == 0 )
                break;
            S->next = lists[min];
            S = S->next;
            if( lists[min] != NULL )
                lists[min] = lists[min]->next;
        }
        return head->next;
    }
};
```

Comment: provide input, current output and expected output.

Comment: What if all the lists are empty? The loop `while (lists[k] == NULL) ++k;` will melt your processor.

Comment: if all the lists are empty K should become equal to N(number of lists) and loop should break, head->next should be returned, which should be NULL
what do you mean it will melt the processor, shouldn't it just loop through the vector and if the lists are empty just increment K?

Comment: `N` does not appear in that `while` loop at all. How would it break? You'll get UB when `k` hits `lists.size()`.

Comment: "Melt a processor" was just a joke. :) You'll get undefined behaviour.

Comment: I see, edited the code, error is still there

Comment: The condition `lists[k] == NULL && k < N` is wrong! You first access out-of-bounds element and only then check if `k < N`.

Comment: yes, just figured it out, @Evg is right, first I have to check if k<N and then check if lists[k] == NULL

Comment: Aside: In C++ it is spelled `nullptr`

Answer (score 0):

If you prune `lists` to only having non-empty lists, you can drop most of the checks for `nullptr`. You are also leaking `head`.

```
bool compareNode(ListNode * lhs, ListNode * rhs) {
    return lhs->val < rhs->val;
}

ListNode* mergeKLists(std::vector<ListNode*>& lists) {
    lists.erase(std::remove(lists.begin(), lists.end(), nullptr), lists.end());

    ListNode* head = nullptr;
    ListNode* curr = nullptr;
    
    while ( !lists.empty() )
    {
        auto it = std::min_element(lists.begin(), lists.end(), compareNode);
        if(head) {
            curr->next = *it;
        } else {
            curr = head = *it;
        }

        if (ListNode* next = (*it)->next) {
            *it = next;
        } else {
            lists.erase(it);
        }
    }

    return head;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

so the problem was this condition:

```
while( lists[k] == NULL && k < N )
            ++k;
```

when K = N - 1, the conditions are satisfied and k is incremented and becomes N, then it tries to access lists[N] which is out of bounds, therefore the error.
fixed it as:

```
while( k < N && lists[k] == NULL )
            ++k;
```

Now it's working, thanks for the answers :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand the requirement, you want merge all-lists in one output-list when all members are in an ascending order.

```
#include <list>
#include <vector>
#include <map>

// 'Merge' function:

std::list<int> merge(std::vector<std::list<int>>& rlists)
{
    std::map<int, int> map;
    for (auto list : rlists)
        for (auto i : list)
            map[i]++;

    std::list<int> onelist;
    for (auto item : map)
        for (int i = item.second; i > 0; i--)
            onelist.push_back(item.first);

    return onelist;
}

//////////////// Use Case: ////////////////

int main()
{
    std::vector<std::list<int>> lists;

    lists.push_back(std::list<int>{ 1, 4, 5 });
    lists.push_back(std::list<int>{}); // Empty
    lists.push_back(std::list<int>{ 1, 3, 4 });
    lists.push_back(std::list<int>{ 2, 6 });

    std::list<int> onelist(merge(lists));
}
```